# How can I connect Cloud SQL for MySQL to my flutter app and use Firebase for authentication?

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-platform

What I'm trying to do is use Cloud SQL for MySQL for my database and use Firebase for auth and push notifications. What I can't figure out is how can I match a Singed In user with the corresponding user in my MySQL database to fetch the users data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using Firebase Authentication, you'll typically use the UID of those users to associate them with their data in the database. Instead of using a foreign key, it'll just be a string value - as there's no target in the database for a foreign key to point to.

After that, it should be possible to query on the UID values as you would do on other fields too. If you're having a problem with that, edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: If I understood correctly in, let's say, the User table there should be a field for the firebase UID, correct? If it's that thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a table with the users in your MySQL database, that'd be a good place to store each user's Firebase UID too indeed.